# Largest interval over which the general solution is defined (Differential Equations)

Tags: calculus

**Consider the following differential equation:**

x  $\frac{dy}{dx} $ - y =     ${x^2}$  $\sin{x}$

**P(x):**

P(x) = -$\frac{1}{x}$

**Integrating Factor:**

$\frac{1}{x}$

**Found General Solution:**

y(x) = -x $\cos{x}$+Cx

**Question:**

"Give the largest interval over which the general solution is defined. (Think about the implications of any singular points. Enter your answer using interval notation.)"

How do you find this? I have trouble understanding intervals for functions. If anyone can explain how to find this in the simplest way possible because this is something my brain can't wrap my head around.

I appreciate it & Thank you!

Comment: you mean :
$$x \dfrac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x} - y = x^2 \sin x$$

Comment: Yes that's what i mean.